# How to link a webhosting service to github repository

Tags: php, git, github, ftp, web-hosting

I have hosted my website using crazydomains.com. They are similar to go daddy and other hosting services. 
The code for the website is uploaded using an ssh client or ftp login.
Is there a way so that i can link my master on github to the ftp directory on my hosting service so that i dont have to keep downloading from github and uploading to the host server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can login via ssh and check if git is installed there. `git --version`

If git is installed, you could simply clone your git repo. You will need to generate ssh key pair for this particular server and add it to your github account so it can see your private repos.

Alternatively you can ask support if they support something like this on hosting plans you have.